# How to remove a group from implied list and a remove a user from a group in Odoo13?

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

I am trying to remove the group 'base.group_no_one`from the group`base.group_user`. Also I tried to remove the default template user` base.default_user`from the`base.group_no_one`.

Here is what I tried,

Remove the implied ids,

```
        <record id="base.group_user" model="res.groups">
        <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(3, ref('base.group_no_one'))]"/>
    </record>
```

Remove the user

```
    <record id="base.group_no_one" model="res.groups">
        <field name="users" eval="[(3, ref('base.default_user'))]"/>
    </record>
```

But it didn't work.